# Want to create multiple actions for my character

Tags: actions

this is Alfred and I am currently making actions for my character on Blender.

[image: It was made following online tutorial]

I have already made one action and still want to make more

[image: The actions of armature]

And want to ask how to continue to make other actions for the same character and armature? Cuz I wish to import it to unity and want the file size be minimized, thx a lot for your reading and help!

Comment: You want to save each animation as a separate sequence/strip

Comment: exactly! just want to save as different actions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently workin in the dope sheet editor. To be able to work with multiple animations, you'll have to switch to the action editor.

[image]
to
[image]

Now create an animation by clicking the 'new' button.

When your first action is finished, don't forget to click the 'F' button next to your action name to save a 'fake-copy' so your animation doesn't get lost, because it is not the active action, when you reload/re-open your file.

[image]

Comment: Thank very much, I tried it but when I created it by action editor and create new animation, the new one will cover the old one, is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I think you can select all keyframes and copy paste them into your new action...

Comment: If this answer was succesfull, please mark this answer as the solution!

Comment: but how do u make multiple actions, not simply copy part of one to another?